# Haproxy: Slow responses for static content

Tags: nginx, haproxy

We're using HAProxy for load balancing. Our application is running on 10 Caucho Resin servers and 7 dedicated Nginx servers (this for static content).

Versions:

```
HA-Proxy version 1.5-dev19 2013/06/17
nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

My problem at this moment is a super slow response of the static content such as JS, CSS and image files. When I curl or wget some files through HAproxy, response times are too high like ~3 seconds or more, but if I do the same but, getting them directly from Nginx servers responses are near ~300ms to ~600ms which is way better instead.

I've done a small test with ab, using 10 connections with concurrency of 10.

Through HAProxy:

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      336  340   2.7    341     343
Processing:   425  779 738.3    471    2687
Waiting:      209  459 710.0    241    2479
Total:        760 1119 739.7    812    3030

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    812
  66%    824
  75%    826
  80%   1782
  90%   3030
  95%   3030
  98%   3030
  99%   3030
 100%   3030 (longest request)
```

Direct Nginx connection:

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      193  202   3.9    203     205
Processing:   424  437  10.8    438     455
Waiting:      220  239  12.1    241     257
Total:        620  639  13.4    641     659

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    641
  66%    646
  75%    647
  80%    654
  90%    659
  95%    659
  98%    659
  99%    659
 100%    659 (longest request)
```

As you can see, we have some kind of problem there.

Both Nginx's and HAproxy has a tweaked sysctl and improved ulimits, running on Intel Gigabit's cards and Cisco Catalyst Switches.

Haproxy's sysctl:

```
#-------------------------------------------
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1

net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_interval = 3600
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_stale_time = 3600
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 4096
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 2048
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 1024

net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65023
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 10240
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 400000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 60000
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 3
net.core.somaxconn = 16384
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 12

net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 2048

net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 50576   64768   98152
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 2048

#----------------------------------------
```

Nginx's sysctl:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15
kernel.sysrq = 1
kernel.panic = 20
kernel.panic_on_oops = 5
fs.file-max = 200000
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 2000 65000
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 3240000
net.core.somaxconn = 3240000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
net.core.rmem_default = 8388608
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic
```

And HAproxy's configuration:

```
global
    maxconn 160000
    spread-checks   5
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 warning
    stats socket /etc/haproxy/haproxysock level admin
defaults
    log global
    mode http
    balance leastconn
    option redispatch # any server can handle any session
    option http-server-close
    timeout client 20s
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout server 30s
    timeout queue 25s
    timeout check 2s
    timeout http-request 15s
    timeout http-keep-alive 5s
    maxconn 160000
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
    errorfile 408 /dev/null

frontend incoming my-public-ip:80
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http

    stick-table type ip size 1m expire 1m store gpc0,http_req_rate(10s),http_err_rate(10s)
    tcp-request connection track-sc1 src
    tcp-request connection reject if { src_get_gpc0 gt 0 }
    http-request deny if { src_get_gpc0 gt 0 }


    #Different ACL for JS/CSS/Fonts
    acl staticjs    path_end .js    
    acl staticjs    path_end .css
    acl staticjs    path_end .woff


    #Static
    acl staticacl hdr_dom(host) -i static.mydomain.com
    acl staticacl hdr_dom(host) -i static.myotherdomain.com

    #Dynamic
    acl dynacl hdr_dom(host) -i mydomain.com
    acl dynacl hdr_dom(host) -i www.mydomain.com
    acl dynacl hdr_dom(host) -i myanotherdomain.com
    acl dynacl hdr_dom(host) -i www.myanotherdomain.com



    use_backend static if staticacl
    use_backend dynamic if dynacl
    use_backend staticcssjs if staticjs
    default_backend dynamic

backend dynamic :80
    acl abuse src_http_req_rate(incoming) ge 700
    acl flag_abuser src_inc_gpc0(incoming)
    tcp-request content reject if abuse flag_abuser
    http-request deny if abuse flag_abuser
    option  http-server-close
    server resin6 192.168.1.75:8080 check
        server resin6-2 192.168.1.75:8081 check
        server resin5 192.168.1.73:8080 check
        server resin5-2 192.168.1.73:8081 check
        server resin4 192.168.1.59:8080 check
        server resin4-2 192.168.1.59:8081 check
        server resin3 192.168.1.53:8080 check
        server resin3-2 192.168.1.53:8081 check
        server resin2 192.168.1.52:8080 check
        server resin2-2 192.168.1.52:8081 check


backend static :80
    option abortonclose 
    acl abuse src_http_req_rate(incoming) ge 2300
    acl flag_abuser src_inc_gpc0(incoming)
    tcp-request content reject if abuse flag_abuser
    http-request deny if abuse flag_abuser

        server cache1 192.168.1.54:81 check weight 100
        server cache2 192.168.1.55:81 check weight 100
        server cache3 192.168.1.68:81 check weight 100
        server cache4 192.168.1.69:81 check weight 100
        server static1 192.168.1.54:67 check weight 80 
        server static2 192.168.1.55:67 check weight 80
        server static3 192.168.1.68:67 check weight 80
        server static4 192.168.1.69:67 check weight 80

backend staticcssjs :80
        option abortonclose
        acl abuse src_http_req_rate(incoming) ge 2300
        acl flag_abuser src_inc_gpc0(incoming)
        tcp-request content reject if abuse flag_abuser
        http-request deny if abuse flag_abuser
    server static5  192.168.1.74:67 check weight 50
    server static6  192.168.1.82:67 check weight 50
```

Do you guys experimented something similar? This is driving me crazy. Actually we have ~15k connections to our balancer:

```
root@haproxy:~# netstat -talpn | grep mypublicip | wc -l
15656
```

Which more of them are TIME_WAIT connections:

```
root@haproxy:~# netstat -talpn | grep mypublicip | grep WAIT | wc -l
14472
root@haproxy:~# netstat -talpn | grep mypublicip | grep EST | wc -l
1172
root@haproxy:~# netstat -talpn | grep mypublicip | grep LISTEN | wc -l
2
```

An output of `vmstat 1` does not show me any problem

```
root@haproxy:~# vmstat 1
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 1  0      0 6886204 395364 527264    0    0     0     1    0    0  1  3 96  0
 0  0      0 6883684 395364 527288    0    0     0     0 17458 10061  2  4 94  0
 0  0      0 6885056 395364 527288    0    0     0     0 18165 17773  2  4 94  0
 1  0      0 6883428 395364 527288    0    0     0     0 16436 14367  2  4 93  0
 1  0      0 6882928 395364 527288    0    0     0     0 16330 10098  2  3 95  0
 0  0      0 6884584 395364 527288    0    0     0    16 16579 9063  3  4 92  0
 1  0      0 6885632 395364 527292    0    0     0    12 14936 11526  2  3 95  0
 1  0      0 6884028 395364 527292    0    0     0     0 16808 13303  2  4 93  0
 0  0      0 6884408 395364 527292    0    0     0     0 16623 8892  2  4 94  0
 1  0      0 6884896 395364 527292    0    0     0     0 14480 8565  2  3 95  0
 1  0      0 6884532 395364 527292    0    0     0     0 14760 10602  1  3 95  0
```

May 33% of CPU is too much? We are running on an AMD Opteron 4133 (8 Cores/processors)

root@NaventLB1:~# top

```
top - 08:28:25 up 230 days, 15:08,  5 users,  load average: 0.51, 0.36, 0.34
Tasks: 145 total,   3 running, 142 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.4%us,  1.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8162012k total,  1276420k used,  6885592k free,   395364k buffers
Swap:  9764860k total,        0k used,  9764860k free,   527432k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                       
10199 haproxy   20   0  103m  56m  732 R   33  0.7  17:57.96 haproxy                                                                                                                                        
64385 www-data  20   0 4098m  26m 1860 S    4  0.3   1387:14 pound                                                                                                                                          
    1 root      20   0 24320 2196 1272 S    0  0.0   5:46.10 init
```

Cheers!

Comment: Network congestion with some Packet loss? If I recall correctly, 3 seconds is a suspicious figure in terms of TCP retransmission timeouts. Do you ever see 9 seconds for the slowest request? If not that, then post the whole request and response from each step in the chain so we can see the various headers.

Comment: The haproxy logs include a lot of useful information for tracking this type of stuff. I suggest providing a few specific examples.

Comment: What patrick said, in particular we will want to see the timers section of the log for these slow requests.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved (or sort of) my problem using another HAProxy to serve static content, by this way performance now is very high and response times are way better than before.

Anyway, I will be studying what happend with this.